# Dynamically load CSS to document head and wait after load

Tags: jquery, css, iframe, load, domdocument

How can I dynamicaly add CSS files to document HEAD and wait until the files is fully loaded? I'm using iframe so here is my example how I'm inserting CSS dynamicaly to document loaded in iframe.

```
$(iframe).contents().find('head').append('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />');
```

This code only add CSS file, but I need to do some action after its content is loaded. Any idea?
I'm open to every option, but the content of the CSS file should not be inserted as inline code.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you know something about jQuery.
This can be used to check if a stylesheet has been succesfully loaded:

```
if($("link[href='/path/to.css']").length)){
 // CSS succesfully loaded.
}
```

Now let's build this function you're after.
You are appending a stylesheet into the head, so when the head element changes you want to check if the CSS is succesfully loaded and then do something awesome. (or do nothing until the CSS is loaded using some variables etc..)

```
$("head").change(function(){
   var url = "/path/to/stylesheet.css";
   if($("link[href='" + url + "']").length)){
     // CSS succesfully loaded.
   } else {
     // some problems with the CSS
   }
});
```

If this is not what you are looking for, I hope this will at least get you started with something.

Best regards,